# Calculate the variance from a function of normal random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variables, invariance

I am new to the topic that I found difficulty for the question:

> Given the function $g(x) = e^{-X}$, $X  \sim N(0,1)$, calculate the variance of $g(x)$.

I know the answer is $e(e-1)$. But I don't know how to get that. Can anyone help?

In additions, would anyone provide me a book that may explore this area?

Thanks.

Comment: For starters, did you compute E(g(X))?

Comment: OK, even simpler: how do you compute E[X]? I am not talking about saying "this is a gaussian hence I know the mean", I am talking about writing down the formula you would use if you were trying to compute E[X].